# numpy array multiplication slower than for loop with vector multiplication?

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy, cython

I have come across the following issue when multiplying numpy arrays.  In the example below (which is slightly simplified from the real version I am dealing with), I start with a nearly empty array `A` and a full array `C`.  I then use a recursive algorithm to fill in `A`.

Below, I perform this algorithm in two different ways.  The first method involves the operations

```py
n_array = np.arange(0,c-1)
temp_vec= C[c-n_array] * A[n_array]
A[c] += temp_vec.sum(axis=0)
```

while the second method involves the for loop

```py
for m in range(0, c - 1):
    B[c] +=  C[c-m] * B[m]
```

Note that the arrays A and B are identical, but they are filled in using the two different methods.

In the example below I time how long it takes to perform the computation using each method.  I find that, for example, with `n_pix=2` and `max_counts = 400`, the first method is much faster than the second (that is, `time_np` is much smaller than `time_for`).  However, when I then switch to, for example, `n_pix=1000` and `max_counts = 400`, instead I find method 2 is much faster (`time_for` is much smaller than `time_np`).  I would have thought that method 1 would always be faster since method 2 explicitly runs over a loop while method 1 uses `np.multiply`.

So, I have two questions:

1. Why does the timing behave this way as a function of `n_pix` for a fixed `max_counts`?
2. What is optimal method for writing this code so that it behaves quickly for all `n_pix`?

That is, can anyone suggest a method 3?  In my project, it is very important for this piece of code to perform quickly over a range of large and small `n_pix`.

```py
import numpy as np
import time

def return_timing(n_pix,max_counts):
    A=np.zeros((max_counts+1,n_pix))
    A[0]=np.random.random(n_pix)*1.8
    A[1]=np.random.random(n_pix)*2.3

    B=np.zeros((max_counts+1,n_pix))
    B[0]=A[0]
    B[1]=A[1]

    C=np.outer(np.random.random(max_counts+1),np.random.random(n_pix))*3.24

    time_np=0
    time_for=0
    for c in range(2, max_counts + 1):

        t0 = time.time()
        n_array = np.arange(0,c-1)
        temp_vec= C[c-n_array] * A[n_array]
        A[c] += temp_vec.sum(axis=0) 
        time_np += time.time()-t0

        t0 = time.time()
        for m in range(0, c - 1):
            B[c] +=  C[c-m] * B[m]  
        time_for += time.time()-t0
    return time_np, time_for
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, you can easily replace:

```
n_array = np.arange(0,c-1)
temp_vec= C[c-n_array] * A[n_array]
A[c] += temp_vec.sum(axis=0)
```

with:

```
A[c] += (C[c:1:-1] * A[:c-1]).sum(0)
```

This is much faster because indexing with an array is much slower than slicing. But the `temp_vec` is still hidden in there, created before summing is done. This leads to the idea of using [`einsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html), which is the fastest because it doesn't make the temp array.

```
A[c] = np.einsum('ij,ij->j', C[c:1:-1], A[:c-1])
```

Timing. For small arrays:

```
>>> return_timing(10,10)
numpy OP    0.000525951385498
loop OP     0.000250101089478
numpy slice 0.000246047973633
einsum      0.000170946121216
```

For large:

```
>>> return_timing(1000,100)
numpy OP    0.185983896255
loop OP     0.0458009243011
numpy slice 0.038364648819
einsum      0.0167834758759
```

Answer (score 4):

It is probably because your numpy-only version requires creation/allocation of new ndarrays (`temp_vec` and `n_array`), while your other method does not.

Creation of new ndarrays is very slow and if you can modify your code in such a way that it no longer have to continuously create them, I would expect that you could get better performance out of that method.